# Creating a right to left off screen sub-menu navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on mobile navigation and at the moment my navigation items all appear stacked on top of each other. I would like to have it so when you click on a top level link the nav slides over from the right to show the next sub-menu...with a back button to take you back a level.

A prime example of what I'm looking to achieve is the 'House of Fraser' mobile nav menu...apologies as I'm just not sure of the correct term for this style of nav, there are so many options.

Example of what I've started with -

https://jsfiddle.net/StuartP/pp9664bs/3/

```
<nav id="navxs">
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Level1</a>
                <div class="container">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Level2</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Level 3</a>
                                        <a href="#">Level 3</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                        </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Level2</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Level 3</a>
                                        <a href="#">Level 3</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
            </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>
</div>

</nav>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
</script>
```

Only 'Level 1' should show when the menu collapses, then when you click/tap 'Level 1' then the 'Level 2' menu should slide in from the right and so one for level 3.

Any help would greatly appreciated

Thanks
Stuart

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else who comes across this post...I finally managed to find what I was looking for here -

http://github.danielcardoso.net/sliding-menu/#

I'd really need to have got up to speed with my Javascript to even remotely think about putting this together so thank you to Daniel Cardoso for your elegant sliding navigation and again to Tobii for the cascading nav option.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to achieve that what you want, I made a few changes to your code.

First, I needed to make sure that the individual levels don't overlap each other in the menu. In order to do that, I added this `padding-left:20px;` to the code in the `ul` css.

```
    ul li {
      list-style: none;   
      padding-left:20px;  /*added this line*/
    }
```

Second, I needed to modify you `openNav()` to receive one parameter, a number. Based on that number, you know which level you are on, and can modify the width of the `mySidenav` element.

Third, I made you a button to reverse the movement.

This all works as long you are consistent with the width of the a tags, or if you can't do that, play a little with the padding of the `ul` element, in order to move the lower levels further in the `mySidenav` div.

Also, there is a reason, why I added the `number * 70` and/or `65` to the code, that is because of the paddings of you starting code. I had no time to dive in you code to deep, and find out what exactly causes there are, but you can, in order to optimize the code and get rid of the `70 px`.

```
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = number * 70 + 50 + width + "px";
```

Good luck, and here is a working example
PS. run it in full screen mode ;)

```js
openNav = function(number) {
    var width =  document.getElementById("mySidenav").clientWidth;
    if (number == 1) {
      if (width == 0) {
       document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = number * 70 + 50 + width + "px";
       document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = number * 70 + 50 + width + "px";
      }
    } else if (number==2){
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = 65 +  120 + "px";
     document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = 65 +  120 + "px";
    } else {
       document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = 65 +  185 + "px";
       document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = 65 +  185 + "px";
    }
}

closeNav = function() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}

backOneLevel = function() {
   var width =  document.getElementById("mySidenav").clientWidth;
   if (width > 120) {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = width - 65 + "px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = width - 65 + "px";
   } else {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
   }
  
}
```

```css
ul li {
   list-style: none;   
      padding-left:20px;  /*added this line*/
}
  
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
     overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

 .sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
 }

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
 .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
 .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<nav id="navxs">

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="#" onclick="openNav(2)" >Level1</a>
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="openNav(3)">Level2</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Level 3</a>
                <a href="#">Level 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="openNav(3)">Level2</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Level 3</a>
                <a href="#">Level 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav(1)">&#9776; </span>
  <button type="button" onclick="backOneLevel()">Go one level back</button>
</div>

</nav>
```

Comment: I like how you can just keep pressing Level1 to expand infinitely.

Comment: fail :), give me a sec

Comment: Ok, I hope it's better now, it's a dirty solution, but I have no nerve to go into the css :)

Comment: Newbie, thanks for looking at this...I'll have a play around with it and hopefully it points me in the right direction.  I'm actually wondering if I should wrap each UL in a div and then that would scroll through to the next div and show the next level of list items, rather than a cascading list